# Oracle query runs very slow due to large dataset and negative values

Tags: oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have been working on writing a query that hits our company's very large database in order to pull back maximum billing amounts (A and B, in this example) for customers. We want to pull back the max A/B for every customer for the past month and the max A/B for the past year.

One issue we noticed with our billing database is the way it stores "canceled" bills. It does so by adding a second, negative version of the first billing record to the billing table. Like so:

[image]

In this case 41040 was the incorrect bill, so a negative version of the record was added. However, when I'm trying to select the max value on this column I will still get back 41040 instead of the correct billed value of 50. This table doesn't seem to flag these incorrect bills in any way that would make them easy to filter out.

My current solution has been to take the maximum value of the ID column as the correct bill. This makes the assumption that the final bill that was entered for a month is the correct one.

This seems to bring back the correct data, but the query runs incredibly slowly on the large data set, and I don't have write access to this table to add or view indexes. There are 98,007,807 rows total and 1,596,491 unique customers and Is there anyway to optimize the query to improve the performance?

```
select mth.KY_CUSTOMER_NO,max(QY_MTH_BILLED_A) as QY_MTH_BILLED_A, max(QY_MTH_B) as QY_MTH_BILLING_B, max.MAX_BILLING_A, max.MAX_BILLING_B
from (
    --Get the max A/B values for the past month
    select m.*
    from CUSTOMER_USAGE m
    where rev_year = to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'))
    and rev_mth in (to_number(to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'mm')),to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mm')))
    and ID in (select max(ID) from CUSTOMER_USAGE where KY_CUSTOMER_NO = m.KY_CUSTOMER_NO group by rev_mth, rev_year)
) mth join 
(
    --Get the max A/B values for the past year
    select KY_CUSTOMER_NO, max(QY_MTH_B) as MAX_BILLING_B, max(QY_MTH_BILLED_A) as MAX_BILLING_A from CUSTOMER_USAGE m
    where DT_ADDED > current_timestamp - 365 ID in (select max(ID) from CUSTOMER_USAGE  where KY_CUSTOMER_NO = m.KY_CUSTOMER_NO group by rev_mth, rev_year)
    group by KY_CUSTOMER_NO
) max on mth.KY_CUSTOMER_NO = max.KY_CUSTOMER_NO
group by mth.KY_CUSTOMER_NO, max.MAX_BILLING_KVA, max.MAX_BILLING_KW
```

Comment: What index(es) exist and what is the current query plan?

Answer (score 1):

Analytic functions appear to be the solution.

I've left out the `WHERE` clauses as they aren't needed for your sample data but you should be able to add them back in to the inner-most inline view. You can also use `EXTRACT( YEAR FROM SYSDATE )` instead of converting to and from a string.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_usage ( id, ky_customer_no, rev_mth, rev_year, qy_mth_billed_a, qy_mth_billed_b ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 2016,  41040, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 1, 2016, -41040, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 1, 2016,     50, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 1, 2016,      0, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       ky_customer_no,
       rev_mth,
       rev_year,
       qy_mth_billed_a,
       qy_mth_billed_b
FROM   (
  SELECT c.*,
         ROW_NUMBER()
           OVER ( PARTITION BY ky_customer_no, rev_year, rev_mth
                  ORDER BY total_mth_billed_a DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT c.*,
           SUM( qy_mth_billed_a )
             OVER ( PARTITION BY ky_customer_no, rev_year, rev_mth, ABS( qy_mth_billed_a )
                    ORDER BY id DESC ) AS total_mth_billed_a               
    FROM   customer_usage c
  ) c
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID KY_CUSTOMER_NO    REV_MTH   REV_YEAR QY_MTH_BILLED_A QY_MTH_BILLED_B
---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ---------------
         3              1          1       2016              50               0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried another approach but using most of @MT0 setup.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_usage ( id, ky_customer_no, rev_mth, rev_year, qy_mth_billed_a, qy_mth_billed_b ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 2016,  41040, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 1, 2016, -41040, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 1, 2016,     50, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 1, 2016,      0, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Since we want to get rid of those values whose ABS() is equal but the have different signs I tried this:

```
  SELECT c.KY_CUSTOMER_NO, c.REV_MTH, c.REV_YEAR, max(qy_mth_billed_a) as qy_mth_billed_a , max(QY_MTH_BILLED_B) as qy_mth_billed_b
  FROM   (
    SELECT c.*,
           max( qy_mth_billed_a )
             OVER ( PARTITION BY ky_customer_no, rev_year, rev_mth,ABS( qy_mth_billed_a )) AS max_mth_billed_a,
           min( qy_mth_billed_a )
             OVER ( PARTITION BY ky_customer_no, rev_year, rev_mth,ABS( qy_mth_billed_a )) AS min_mth_billed_a      
    FROM   customer_usage c
  ) c where max_mth_billed_a+min_mth_billed_a!=0
group by  c.KY_CUSTOMER_NO, c.REV_MTH, c.REV_YEAR;
```

The output it's the same and, since you are facing some performance problems, I'd try both approaches:

```
KY_CUSTOMER_NO  REV_MTH REV_YEAR    qy_mth_billed_a qy_mth_billed_b
1   1   1   2016    50  0
```

**EDIT**
Actually if you count the different signs of each abs(value) and it's an odd number I think it'll work even faster (just one window function needed)

```
SELECT c.KY_CUSTOMER_NO, c.REV_MTH, c.REV_YEAR, max(qy_mth_billed_a) as qy_mth_billed_a , max(QY_MTH_BILLED_B) as qy_mth_billed_b
  FROM   (
    SELECT c.*,
           count(sign( qy_mth_billed_a ))
             OVER ( PARTITION BY ky_customer_no, rev_year, rev_mth,ABS( qy_mth_billed_a )) AS signo    
    FROM   customer_usage c
  ) c where mod(signo,2) =1
group by  c.KY_CUSTOMER_NO, c.REV_MTH, c.REV_YEAR
```